# Calls in viewDidAppear not calling with constraints added

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

In my code I have a viewWillAppear call which is like the one below designed to move certain objects out of the way.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        playButton.center.x -= view.bounds.width
        howToButton.center.x -= view.bounds.width
        imageView1.center.x = view.bounds.width - (imageView1.frame.width / 2)
        imageView2.center.x = view.bounds.width - (imageView2.frame.width / 2)
        imageView1.center.x += imageView1.frame.width
        imageView2.center.x += imageView2.frame.width
        introductoryLabel.alpha = 0
    }
```

This is followed by a viewDidAppear call which animates these objects into scene. My problem is that the viewDidAppear does the animations (which basically reverses what's in viewWillAppear) as if viewWillAppear hadn't been called. Interestingly this is only a problem when I apply constraints in the storyboard. How can I keep the constraints but allow viewDidAppear to do its thing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Interestingly this is only a problem when I apply constraints in the storyboard

This is not at all surprising. If you have applied constraints, you *cannot* then change the `center` of your views. Well, you can, but it is useless to do so, because the constraints will then proceed to reposition them according to the constraints. That, after all, is the *purpose* of constraints!

So, basically, there are two ways to position things: using their `frame` or `center`, on the one hand, and using constraints, on the other hand. Don't try to mix them together. Use one or the other.

Comment: So how do I get the constraints to size up the objects in the frame to their correct sizes and then do the animations?

Comment: I don't know what you _want_ to do, so I cannot tell you how to do it. Your question was why the views jumped back to their original position, and I answered that. However, the simple answer is: change the _constraints_, not the `center`.

Comment: I realised when you answered that my question was a little vague. What I need is for me to execute the code provided before the view appears while ensuring that the constraints have done their job

Comment: I don't know what that means. That is exactly what _is_ happening. The code is executed, and then the constraints do their job. The constraints don't stop doing their job! Don't fight them. You will lose the fight.

Comment: I mean as soon as the buttons and views are positioned as per constraints, how do I then keep the shape of the elements in the scene, remove the constraints, animate their entrance and put them back again

Comment: I already told you that. Change the _constraints_, not the `center`. And when you later animate the views to reposition, animate the _change of constraints_ — again, don't change the `center`. Another alternative to this whole thing: don't use constraints! They are what is messing you up, after all.

Comment: But how can I change the constraints?

Comment: If the only difference is the `constant` of a constraint, just change the `constant`. Otherwise, remove the constraint and replace it by a different constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help but you should call super.viewDidAppear(animated) like this:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            super.viewWillAppear(animated) // This is what you may be missing

            playButton.center.x -= view.bounds.width
            howToButton.center.x -= view.bounds.width
            imageView1.center.x = view.bounds.width - (imageView1.frame.width / 2)
            imageView2.center.x = view.bounds.width - (imageView2.frame.width / 2)
            imageView1.center.x += imageView1.frame.width
            imageView2.center.x += imageView2.frame.width
            introductoryLabel.alpha = 0
        }
```

Comment: It's not a problem with the call as introductoryLabel.alpha = 0 checks out.

Answer (score 0):

Views from Xib or Storyboard are still repositioning in `willWillApear`,`willDidApear` methods so you cannont change the view's frame. If you really want to do this, change them after some delay,eg. 0.25s, or you can change them in `viewDidLayoutSubViews` method.(Not recommended,called multiple times).Furthermore,you can animate the views by changing `view.transform` or change the constraints.

Comment: How small of a delay after viewDidAppear as I need these bits of code to execute immediately after it loads